# How to control the LED on an xbox 360 gamepad using pyusb

Tags: python, usb, pyusb, gamepad

I'm looking to use pyusb to interact with a wired xbox 360 gamepad. So far I can read just fine but I'd also like to write so I can make the LED stop blinking.

Looking [here](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/UsbInfo), I should be able to do it, but no matter what messages I try sending, I'm not having any luck controlling the LED. Below is the code I have thus far, any suggestions?

```
import usb
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=1118, idProduct=654)
dev.set_configuration()
readEP = dev[0][(0,0)][0] #endpoint to read from
writeEP = dev[0][(0,0)][1] #endpoint to write to

print readEP #should be: <ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN>
print writeEP #should be: <ENDPOINT 0x1: Interrupt OUT>

##read the startup messages
for i in range(4): #usually only 4 messages
  data = dev.read(readEP.bEndpointAddress,readEP.wMaxPacketSize,100)
  print len(data) #should be 3

##get initial button/axes state
data = dev.read(readEP.bEndpointAddress,readEP.wMaxPacketSize,100)
print len(data) #should be 20

##Try to set the LED to illuminate just one element (message 0x06).
##Each of the following commented-out attempts fails to leave only the first
##element illuminated and subsequent attempts at reading or writing yields
##"usb.core.USBError: [Errno 5] Input/Output Error"
dev.write(writeEP,'010306',100) 
# dev.write(writeEP,'0\x010306',100) 
# dev.write(writeEP,'66310',100) #decimal value of 0x010306

##attempt to read again
while True:
  data = dev.read(readEP.bEndpointAddress,readEP.wMaxPacketSize,100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it; just had to try more variants of the string being written. Here's what eventually worked:

```
dev.write(writeEP,"\x01\x03\x06",0)
```